# convert php array to json

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have the following code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vendor";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$posts = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
               array_push($posts , $row);
            }
    }
echo"<pre>";
  print_r($posts);
echo "</pre>";

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode('list'=>$posts);
```

$posts contains the array that I need now.I wish to convert it into json.I tried these two methods

```
echo json_encode($posts, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo json_encode($posts)
```

but didn't got any result. my php version is 5.5.21 (CGI)

can anyone please help me with it.

Comment: are you getting the values in `$posts`?

Comment: what is the return value of json_encode? I would assume false. Can you output a possible json error with with http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: @sgt BOSE yes i have value in it

Comment: @Florian i am not getting any error just a blank page

Comment: @kavi: Have you enabled error_reporting? What does your webservers error log say?

Comment: Sounds like your errors are occurring before you start encoding.

Comment: Exactly @Flosculus I think that the query is not resulting anytimg.

Comment: Is the input you're passing to `json_encode()` utf-8 encoded?

Comment: @Florian i used this code for displaying errors  ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL); BUT didn't got any result in return

Comment: @Flosculus when i am running the code print_r i am getting the entire array.

Comment: @Jordy the query is running coz i am able to c the array when i print it

Comment: what happens when you write var_dump() instead of echo? var_dump(json_encode($posts, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE))? And what does json_last_error() return? Can you try to add a simply echo "Hello" to the end of your script to see, if it will be visible?

Comment: @Florian i did all the three things u said and got this o/p bool(false)  5 hello.. can u please tell what it means

Comment: @kavi Can you try to narrow down the culprit data, run this for each row individually.  In theory most of them should encode fine, but once one of them returns `false`, show us that data.

Comment: @kavi Change your `array_push($posts, $row)` to `if (false === json_encode($row)) { print_r($row); die(); }`

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-last-error.php, "5" should be JSON_ERROR_UTF8, rest is some time and googling :D

Comment: @kavi just look at my answer,i think it will help.

Comment: @Flosculus i changed it and got this result Array ( [id] => 1 [phoneno] => 123 [email] => [password] => [staffpick] => [status] => approved [logintype] => ) and i tried with every row, i am getting error while encoding

Comment: @kavi: Just a guess: Can you try setting mysqli_set_charset($mysqliconnection, 'utf8'); directly after you established the mysql-connection? And then try your script again.

Comment: @Florian now i am getting the result, but when i am viewing it through json viewer it says invalid json format

Comment: @kavi what is the charset of your mysql table you get the data from? Is assume it's not utf8, is there a reason why?

Answer (score 0):

To be sure you go in your loop, you should add echo in

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
        echo 'Test 1st Loop';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
               echo 'array_push';
               array_push($posts , $row);
            }
    }
```

don't forget to add

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Its an encoding issue, nothing to do with the assembly of data.

Comment: the header should help

Comment: @xNeyte why should the header help? In the comments of the question we already know, that the json can not decoded with error 5 (UTF8...), header() controls only the header sent to the client, not how the server/php handles the code/data.

Answer (score 0):

After Many trails i have got the solution.
I have done with my local database table,it's  working fine for me.just look at it once.

I have just change my table name and database name.rest of code same.

**Code:-**

```
    <?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "dboard";
    $table = "appusers";
    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    else{
    echo "Connected successfully";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $posts = array();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                {
                   array_push($posts , $row);
                }
        }
echo"<pre>*********Array Data:******</br>";
 print_r($posts);
echo "</pre>";

echo"<pre>@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Json Format Data:@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@</br></pre>";

echo json_encode($posts);  
    ?>
```

Hope this helps,

**Output:-**

```
Connected successfully

*********Array Data:******
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [lastname] => user
            [firstname] => k
            [user] => raj
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [lastname] => user
            [firstname] => k
            [user] => yusuf
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [lastname] => users
            [firstname] => kl
            [user] => raj
        )

)

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Json Format Data:@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

[{"id":"1","lastname":"user","firstname":"k","user":"raj"},{"id":"4","lastname":"user","firstname":"k","user":"yusuf"},{"id":"5","lastname":"users","firstname":"kl","user":"raj"}]
```

Comment: i already have tried but still did it again and it also didn't displayed any result

Comment: do one thing,just print   print_r($posts); and tel me are you got array or not?

Comment: please edit your question with entire code,i will help you where you will done the mistake

Comment: @User your code is same as the post.. not able to c where the changes have been made

Comment: your code is working perfectly in my local system,as i am posted as a answer.but i don't understand why you are facing a problem.

Comment: @kavi do one thing just copy my code and run this  code in your local system with your database credentials and let me know it's working or not.

Comment: @User i did that but i need to work on a live server

Comment: ok kavi,but how can i help you,without seeing your live code?

Comment: why you are using 'list'=>$posts directly print $posts value.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this code...

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn)
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
mysqli_query($conn,"set character_set 'utf8'");
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM vendor ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$posts = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
              array_push($posts , $row);
            }

        echo json_encode(array('list'=>$posts), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);        
    }
else 
    {
        echo stripslashes(json_encode(array('list'=>'No list available')));
    }    
?>
```